# Как из строк в столбик создать json строку?

Tags: php, json

Необходимо email базу контактов, вида

email;name

test1@Yandex.Ru;Ваня

test2@Yandex.Ru;Ирина

преобразовать в json строку следующего вида

`[{"confirmed":true,"email":"test1@yandex.ru","first_name":"\u0412\u0430\u043d\u044f"},{"confirmed":true,"email":"test2@yandex.ru","first_name":"\u0418\u0440\u0438\u043d\u0430"}]`

Сама база в csv файле.
Можно как-то создать такую json строку?

Спасибо!

p.s. экспериментировал с json_encode но запутался.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: Спасибо, уже понятнее стало.

Comment: потом строите массив  такой структуры `var_export(json_decode('[{"confirmed":true,"email":"test1@yandex.ru","first_name":"\u0412\u0430\u043d\u044f"},{"confirmed":true,"email":"test2@yandex.ru","first_name":"\u0418\u0440\u0438\u043d\u0430"}]', true));` и преобразуете `json_encode($arr);`